# Why 'X' + Y = 'XY' in TypeScript ? Expect an error

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand TypeScript and how it works so this is a very simple example :

```js
const X: string = '5';
const Y: number = 6;
console.log(X+Y) // output '56' ! why not an error ? and why not 11 ?
```

With JavaScript, such a result is acceptable, but since TypeScript is designed to avoid logic errors, why it does not mind if we try to append a "string" to a "number". Logically speaking, this makes no sense even for concatenation. also why the default procedure is to treat Y as `string` and concatenate why not try to convert X to `number` and add ?

Comment: You question how far TypeScript is based on a well-defined typed language model, instead of just a _compiled_ (= by aspect redesigned) JavaScript. _(Unfortunately one cannot expect a total new language definition.)_

Comment: To answer the second question, TypeScript **does not modify the runtime behavior of your code**. So that's why it's `"56"`, the same result had you used JavaScript instead.

Comment: I think the logic assumption you're making is that "+" is defined as a operation between two numbers. That is not the case in JS--it's both numeric addition and string concatenation with some automatic conversion built in, and TS types reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the tenets of TypeScript is that "your existing working JavaScript code is also TypeScript code" [[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)].

There's plenty of existing JavaScript code with bits like this:

```
const x = '5';
const y = 6;
console.log(x + y); // '56'
```

and that do expect the behavior of JavaScript. It would be a significant barrier to migration if TypeScript forced developers to change the above. (And it's a nonstarter to suggest that it should output `11`; we couldn't trust TypeScript if renaming a file from `.js` to `.ts` could introduce bugs detectable only at runtime.)

Now, you might want to object that your code is different, in that you explicitly annotate the variables with their types. But TypeScript provides type inference, and it would be a horrible mess if

```
const x : string = '5';
```

produced a variable with slightly different behavior than

```
const x = '5';
```

Language design always involves tradeoffs, and TypeScript has decided that some JavaScript quirks are worth keeping for compatibility.